# How to fix Modulenotfounderror when using external files by os.environ.setdefault in Django

Tags: python, django

I put my module in a folder and tried to use it in conjunction with Django.

this is my project example structure(my_module directory is not a django app, just my custom pakage):

```
    mysite
    |-- my_module
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- mymodule1.py
    |   |-- mymodule2.py
    |   |-- mymodule3.py
    |-- mysite
    |   |-- settings.py
    |   |-- base.py
    |   |-- dev.py
    |   |-- production.py
    |   |--wsgi.py
    |-- myapp
    |-- manage.py
```

in my_module/mymodule1.py

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
django.setup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
# my code...
```

When I run this python file in Pycharm, it runs without any problem.
but, when I run this terminal command 'python mymodule.py' in my_module directory, it occurs error which **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'**"

How can I fix this problem?
and What is the diffrence between runining at Pycharm and terminal command?

Comment: I'm fixed that by adding 
 `sys.path.append(sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))`

But still the question is not solved, because I did print(sys.path), it print 

`[... ,  /Users/name/Desktop/workspace/mysite', ... , ... , ... , '/Users/name/Desktop/workspace/mysite']`


The path I added using sys.path.append() is output as two in sys.path , Then the path already had the path I added.

Even if I tried to print without sys.path.append just in case, the path already existed.
So why am I getting the error before adding sys.path?

Comment: Not sure if this will help. But, you can try to go to the mysite project folder before launching with the command: cd your path to the project folder. Also, your my_module folder with modules is similar to the application package and it may need to be registered in the settings.py module by including it in the INSTALLED_APPS list.